# hook_field_views_data() not picked up in mymodule.views.inc

Tags: views

I have implemented `hook_field_views_data()` in mymodule.views.inc but the hook is not picked up.

In mymodule.module I have the following code to define where mymodule.views.inc resides.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/views',
  );
}
```

Below is the code for views/mymodule.views.inc. And the problem is that if I try dumping out $field for example it seems like hook_field_views_data() is not picked up.

I tried to change mymodule_field_views_data() to mymodule_views_data, and that function is picked up. I tried this just to be sure that the file is included at all.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_views_data().
 */
function mymodule_field_views_data($field) {
  $data = field_views_field_default_views_data($field);

  // Add a handler for localities.
  foreach ($field['storage']['details']['sql'] as $type => $tables) {
    foreach ($tables as $table_name => $columns) {
      if (!isset($columns['locality'])) {
        continue;
      }

      $column_real_name = $columns['locality'];
      if (!isset($data[$table_name][$column_real_name]['filter'])) {
        continue;
      }

      $data[$table_name][$column_real_name]['filter']['handler'] = 'mymodule_views_handler_filter_locality';
    }
  }

  return $data;
}
```

mymodule.info

```
name = mymodule
description = Bla bla
core = 7.x

files[] = views/mymodule_views_handler_filter_locality.inc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be the correct behaviour.

If you look at the code for [`field_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!field.views.inc/function/field_views_data/7):

```
function field_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  foreach (field_info_fields() as $field) {
    if ($field['storage']['type'] != 'field_sql_storage') {
      continue;
    }

    $module = $field['module'];
    $result = (array) module_invoke($module, 'field_views_data', $field);

    if (empty($result)) {
      $result = field_views_field_default_views_data($field);
    }
    drupal_alter('field_views_data', $result, $field, $module);

    if (is_array($result)) {
      $data = drupal_array_merge_deep($result, $data);
    }
  }

  return $data;
}
```

You can see it only invokes `hook_field_views_data()` for the module that defines the field. So in the case of (what looks like) an addressfield, the function Views will call has to be called `addressfield_field_views_data()`.

It's more likely you're looking for `hook_field_views_data_alter()` which will allow you to alter existing definitions.

But if that doesn't do what you need, you might have to actually define the `addressfield_field_views_data()` function yourself on behalf of addressfield (if it's not already implemented somewhere). Should be a pretty quick test to find out.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed out that it has to be the module defining the field that can implement hook_field_views_data(). I will give hook_field_views_data_alter() a go.